# Undefined reference to function accepted by compiler

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, linker-errors

Ok so I have this code:

**str.c:**

```
char *str = "example";
```

**main.c:**

```
int str(void);

int main(void)
{
    str();

    return 0;
}
```

**makefile:**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

all: main

main: main.o str.o

main.o: main.c
str.o: str.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

On the first sight, one might say that it's an undefined reference error or something like that. But the compiler simply accepts this code.

The question is, why don't I get a compile error?

It's clear that the function is not properly defined. If I use gdb to break on the str() call, I get a warning type **Function str not defined.**.

Comment: str(); is called inside the main(), but I don't see the function implementation in str.c. You just assign the string literal to str.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer yes, and that's what is bothering him.

Comment: You have to define the function in str.c and then call the function inside your main. It won't complain function undefined.

Comment: Have you tried to link output files? 
Because the compiler has the signature for the funtion while the linker is responsible for getting its definition (code) and link it where this signature is called

Comment: That's a nice one! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all (as other have pointed out already) if one could have expected an error while "building" the executable `main`, then during the linking phase, namely because `int str(void)` is *not defined* in any translation unit (.c file) so the compiler did not place it in any object file (.o).

But unfortunately you have `char * str = "..."` defined.

C (as opposed to other languages, for example C++) does not annotate functions, it does not create a function-signature, but just only the function's name, a symbol name. It does so as well for all other objects.

So the linker has no other choice but checking the names of the symbols available, and if they match 1:1 to link them. It cannot double check, because the compiler did not put any verification information into the object files.

If you had an implementation (a *definition*, as opposed to just a *declaration*) of `int str(void)` somewhere inside the objects to link, then the linker would have noticed that there is no 1:1 match so something fishy might be going on.

Comment: Plus file-scoped declarations have external linkage by default -- without that, the linker would detect the problem as well. A non-`static` global without a corresponding `extern` declaration in a public header is probably a bug that can lead to an unfortunate situation like this...

Answer (score 1):

### Compiler

Code is compiled without problems.

```
int str(void);   //Compiler needs this to know how to prepare future calls to this function
int main(void) {
    str();       //Here compiler knows about str function and how it looks like
    return 0;
}
```

When `str()` is called in *main.c*, compiler will prepare for call and since before main you have function prototype, compiler knows how to call it and will go further, he is fint with it.

### Linker

Linker is the one who at the end tries to put all functions together and then you will get error like *Function not found* because `str()` function was never actually compiled.

Comment: How come? str() is function. I dont see the function implementation in the provided C file?

Comment: When compiler compiles main.c he don't care about `str()` function.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer, that is the purpose of `extern` declarations. For function `extern` is implicitely applied. There is no need to define the function in the same file. This is the way you are able to use any library function.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is happy if you give a function prototype `int str(void);`, however, the linker will try to resolve the reference and you will get an unresolved reference from it.
That's where the error will come from.
The prototype is your promise to the compiler that the function is defined somewhere.  The linker makes sure you kept that promise.

Comment: I don't think the answers are spot on. The interesting thing is the error is not at linking time, but at execution time.